# AngularJS: How to access attributes defined inside directive from outside

Tags: angularjs

I am using a directive for putting ellipsis on text overflow called angular-ellipsis. If there is enough room for the text, angular-ellipsis doesn't applythe ...'s. I need to know if the ellipsis is being applied to some text or not.

Looking into the code for the directive I can see that it has an attribute that seems to match what I am looking for - attribute.isTruncated:

```
compile: function(elem, attr, linker) {

    return function(scope, element, attributes) {
        /* State Variables */
        attributes.isTruncated = false;
```

It also seems to do something similar by setting the 'data-overflowed' attribute of the element like thus:

```
element.attr('data-overflowed', 'false');
```

Here is a link to the code for the directive, it's not too complicated or long:

https://github.com/dibari/angular-ellipsis/blob/master/src/angular-ellipsis.js

I am wondering can I access either of these attributes from my Controller, and if so how? Forgive me if this is obvious, but I completely new to directives...

Comment: Can you try `angular.element(element).attr('data-overflowed')`?

Comment: I assume you mean the inner element to be the id of the div? ie. angular.element('div-name').attr('data-overflowed') ? I tried that and got the error: 'Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember the "JS" in `AngularJS`.
If you can find your element by its `id` or `class` attribute, then you should be able query it with plain javascript, by using [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute):

```
document.querySelector("#element-id").getAttribute('data-overflowed');
```

It's not a perfect solution because in some test frameworks, you are not guaranteed to have the `document` interface (that's why Angular has the `$document` wrapper), but it gets you what you need (without jQuery!). It would have been simpler if `jqLite` (which is used by [`angular.element`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)) had enabled `find` by ID or classname, and not just by tag name.